# Regex and Price Replacements in R

Tags: r, regex, text

I'm trying clean prices out of series of text vectors in r.  I'm using gsub to detect and replace the code is as follows:

```
vec <- c('$1.00 car', '2.00 car', 'car')

vec.clean <- gsub(vec, '/$\\D+.\\D+\\D+', 'substitute')

vec.clean
```

I end up with:

```
'substitute'
```

And the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In gsub(vec, "\\D+.\\D+\\D+", "substitute") :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The desired output is

```
"substitute car" "2.00 car" "car"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this works for your purpose

```
> gsub("^\\$.*(\\s.*)", "Substitute\\1", vec)
[1] "Substitute car" "2.00 car"       "car"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` with the 'x' as the 'vec' and the pattern to match as the first argument

```
sub("\\$(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "substitute", vec)
#[1] "substitute car" "2.00 car"       "car"
```

---

If we want to switch the arguments, make sure to specify the argument name

```
sub(x = vec, pattern =  "\\$(\\d+\\.\\d+)", replacement = "substitute")
```